# Which he doesn't or does?

Tags: word-usage, phrasing

Here's the context:

A dying man has guilt, and one of the voices in his head is claiming he will experience hell, if he dies with it (the guilt). One voice hints that 'hell is a hoax', and the other then replies:

> Only if he has *no* guilt, *which he doesn’t.*

Should that have been phrased:

> Only if he has *no* guilt, *which he does.*

To indicate that the dying man does actually have guilt, which he mustn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Well in your example, he does have guilt, so the double negative in the first option means that he does have guilt and is therefore correct.

Comment: What does “has guilt” mean?  We don’t say that in English. Do you mean that he **is** guilty, that he **feels** guil(ty), or something else?

Comment: I agree with @MorganFR. _Which he doesn't_ is a supplementary (non-restrictive/defining) relative clause where "which" is interpreted as _has no guilt_, so we understand that _he doesn't have no guilt_, i.e. a double negative

Comment: So, @MorganFR maybe suggest this as an answer if there's nothing more to be added?

Answer (score 1):

The very fact that this question comes up indicates that the phrasing is confusing, and a complete rephrasing is in order.

Perhaps "Only if he is free of guilt, which he isn't."

Comment: Will keep this handy, when doing the upcoming _rewrite_